# ASP.NET Ajax UpdateProgress loads after some delay

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, webforms

I am making use of an UpdateProgress to show a gif image as progressbar.

1> The ASP.NET page has a GridView and upon Imagebutton click I need to show a progressbar then save data from the GRID to database.

2> Followed by call to a stored procedure etc.

This works fine under normal circumstances. But when there is large data in the grid (15000 records). The browser stops responding for a while and then the Progress bar is displayed.

Customer tells me to disable the button/hide the button at all times after it is clicked.

I was able to accomplish this by showing a progress image with gray background that covered the whole window. (except for the case of large data)

I want to know alternatives to minimize the time gap between ImageButton click and the loading of the Progressbar

Steps I have tried :-
1> Use a modalpopup extender to show the same progressbar instead of  UpdateProgress.
2> Add alert box, script inside 'BeginRequestHandler'
3> Use OnClientClick event of ImageButtonClick to show the gray popup then do __doPostBack with 'ImageButton's ID as param

In step 3 I want to try adding 'SetTimeOut' before __doPostBack

Simply hiding the ImageButton would also serve the purpose. Please let me know your valuable advice.

Good day!

Answer (score 1):

If you simple need to hide the button, you can set its display style to "none" on client click:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" ImageUrl="myimage.jpg" OnClientClick="this.style.display='none'" />
```

[ImageButton.OnClientClick](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.imagebutton.onclientclick.aspx) executes before page posts back to the server and the code above will effectively hide the button until page is re-rendered after postback.

Comment: Dear Yuriy, I tried your suggestion but even that was causing a delay. Eventually I had to use paging in the Datagrid to stop the browser from freezing and now the UpdateProgress shows up almost instantly with a pagesize of 1000 records

Comment: Good solution. It's always a good idea to limit amount of rows. Perhaps even 1000 is too much, ordinary user can work with up to 100 records at a time.